# How to copy data from one table to another existing table using Mysql or postman?

Tags: mysql

I am not too sure how I can copy information from an existing table to another existing table.

I am trying to copy the data,username, from the table,user, to another table called gamereview and insert that data into a column name userid.

However I also have other data save in the tables. I only want to copy the data from username to userid, without copying the other datas

These are the columns inside gamereview:

```
`userid
review
rating
date`
```

These are the columns inside user:

```
`email
username
password
birthday
image`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO gamereview
            (userid) 
SELECT username FROM user;
```